# Need help deciding between json and jsonb regarding time series storage in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to store time series data into postgresql. Data are coming into json packages through an http request (using Django). The format is the following:

```
{
"2018-01-01 21:44": 53.2,    
"2018-01-01 21:48": 51.7,    
"2018-01-01 21:52": 48.5,    
...
}
```

I usually get around 700-800 values per day for each registered device. This is not much and I have decided to store all values to one json field (since it can hold data up to 1GB).

However I need to make slices of those data (e.g. from March, 2018 to April 2019, or any other arbitrary - chosen by the user - interval) and I don't think that it is optimal to retrieve the whole json dictionary and make slices in my application. I think slicing should be done in Postgres.

I have read that regarding performance JSONB is better but it does not keep the key sorting (i.e. the timestamps) -- So, I guess JSONB is preferred in cases when the selection of individual records is the priority. Am I right?

Application has some real-time uses (watching data change on a real-time web application) so, performance is critical.

Please, keep in mind that there are no duplicate keys in my timestamped data.

I am inclined towards JSON instead of JSONB. BUt I am not very sure about this.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both choices are wrong. Your data are tabular, and I guarantee that you will be more happy if you store each datum in its own table row, using normal "scalar" data types.

Databases are optimized for storing tables with large numbers of rows, so don't worry.

JSON will make you unhappy as soon as you want to (for example) calculate aggregates on all these values.

Comment: Thank you. Aggregations will be done algorithmically (using Pandas on Python)

Comment: That's also wrong. You want to transfer millions of rows to the client to have a slow Python application there do the number crunching? Think again.

Comment: Thanks. I will do some rethinking. I am using Python/Pandas for many years in other various web applications that I have developed without any considerable problems. I find its functionality very good for my job. But generally I never need to transfer millions of rows. Thousands, maybe.

Comment: For tiny amounts of data, anything will work well enough. I also don't want to say that Pandas is bad. It just seems awkward to me to transfer all the data to the client rather than to aggregate them in the database. Using SQL in the database, it would be as simple as `SELECT sum(value) FROM tab WHERE timestampcol BETWEEN '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-31';`.

Comment: I know. You are right. My main aggregations are by minute, by hour, by day, by week, by month and by year, so I guess all these must be easy to do with SQL (I am not an SQL expert but I have done some aggregations in the past). I will consider your suggestion.

Comment: That would be `SELECT date_trunc('hour', tscol), sum(val) FROM tab GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', tscol);`.

Comment: Thank you. I have done similar queries in the past. I know it is not very hard. One more question, if you feel like answering. So, you are saying that storing billions of rows in a table won't affect performance gradually (I guess I will add some indexing to the timestamp column)?

Comment: That depends. Sequential scans for a few big rows are probably somewhat slower (TOAST) than for many small rows. For index scans, the size of the table doesn't matter.